# How can I do a painless switch from Observable to Flowable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I've got a `dao.players().getPlayers()` that returns `Observable<Player>` and it works good so far when the number of Players is less than `2k`. But for large amount of `Player`s, I receive:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cassandra query 'players.getPlayers()' has failed.

`Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed`
```

I read about

> When to use Observable: You have a flow of no more than 1000 elements at its longest: i.e., you have so few elements over time that there is practically no chance for OOME in your application.
>
> When to use Flowable: Dealing with 10k+ of elements that are generated in some fashion somewhere and thus the chain can tell the source to limit the amount it generates.

So is it a good idea just to convert my code to Flowable like this:

```
players.getPlayers().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```

I believe it's kind of a bad taste to convert between the types this way (I believe I can't change the type of dao.players().getPlayers() method, though.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your Cassandra setup and not with RxJava. Even if it is related to their RxJava driver, converting a faulty `Observable` to `Flowable` is already too late and won't likely fix your underlying problem.

Comment: What do you think about maxConcurrency thing to limit number of active threads? I've got multiple methods like getPlayers() so it may be a reason (there're too many active threads that attempt to read something from Cassandra).

Comment: Alex, please take the initiative and try your ideas upfront. Since we can't see into what you have set up in your environment, we can't provide accurate answers to hypothetical questions relying on your particular setup.